# Cannot Find own symbol Class?

Tags: java, android, class

I have two files which both utilise a specific symbol class "Car". I have chosen this as a recurring pattern throughout the project.

My error:

[image]

```
DBhelper.java:

    package com.example.brad.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by Brad on 21/07/2014.
 */

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import  android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.TextureView;

public class DBhelper {
    public static final String CAR_ID = "id";
    public static final String CAR_PHOTO = "photo";

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CarDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String CARS_TABLE = "Cars";

    private static final String CREATE_CARS_TABLE = "create table "
            + CARS_TABLE + " (" + CAR_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + CAR_PHOTO
            + " blob not null);";

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CARS_TABLE);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CARS_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public void Reset() {
        mDbHelper.onUpgrade(this.mDb, 1, 1);
    }

    public DBhelper(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    }

    public DBhelper open() throws SQLException {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insertCarDetails(**Car** car) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CAR_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(car.getBitmap()));
        mDb.insert(CARS_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public **Car** retriveCarDetails() throws SQLException {
        Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, CARS_TABLE, new String[] { CAR_PHOTO}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(CAR_PHOTO));
            cur.close();
            return new Car(Utility.getPhoto(blob));
        }
        cur.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

InsertandRetriveBlobData:

```
package com.example.brad.myapplication;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

/**
 * Created by Brad on 20/07/2014.
 */


public class InsertandRetriveBlobData extends MyActivity {
    private DBhelper DbHelper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        DbHelper = new DBhelper(this);
        **Car** car_One = new Car(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.photo), 1);
        DbHelper.open();
        DbHelper.insertCarDetails(car_One);
        DbHelper.close();
        car_One = null;
        DbHelper.open();
        car_One = DbHelper.retriveCarDetails();
        DbHelper.close();

        ImageView carphoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
        carphoto.setImageBitmap(car_One.getBitmap());

    }
}
```

I have a feeling it is a slight bug as I am also having errors with any use of `getBitmap()` "Cannot resolve method getBitmap()" despite importing it's library.

Comment: Can you post the code for your `Car` class?

Comment: Hi Taken, it's the bottom of the first code snippet

Comment: That is not a class named `Car`. That is a method named `retriveCarDetails()` which returns a `Car` object. You need something like `public class Car { ... }`.

Comment: In that case I have made a mistake referring to it as a class. I meant Symbol, sorry it's 2:10am haha.

Comment: You can't create or return an object of `Car` if you haven't yet made it as a class. This is why the compiler "Can't find the symbol..." because it doesn't yet exist anywhere.

Comment: Hey, I've been following this:
http://androidsurya.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/insert-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite.html

I was under the impression I wouldn't need a specific class because of the one method.

Comment: Which one method? If you mean `retriveCarDetails()` which in your tutorial is `retriveEmpDetails()` then you misunderstood. They aren't showing an employee class, but it was made somewhere. There is no way around it. To make a `Car` object there must be a `Car` class. Near the bottom of the page under the screenshot of the app click the button that says "Download Source Code" and you will see it includes an employee class in it.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your Car class is in `myapplication` directory along with the other two classes you mentioned here.

And then compile from `myapplication` directory.